# hibernate.show_sql должен ли выводить Transaction, Commit ?

Tags: hibernate, java

В выводе содержатся только информация про CRUD операции, а про транзакции ничего. Так и должно быть?

Answer (score 1):

Да, все правильно так и должно быть. Встроенный логгер Hibernate показывает только SQL выражения, причем в форме `PreparedStatement` - без параметров. Фактически это эквивалентно заданию log4j.properties

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
```

Чтобы увидеть параметры запросов и транзакции надо использовать Log4J включив в log4j.properties категории:

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.transaction=ALL
```

Или тупо включить весь логгинг (будет очень много!) Hibernate через

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=ALL
```

Comment: Большое спасибо) Я уж подумал что их нет) Теперь живу, что есть)